# Anaconda Navigator がロード中のまま起動しない

Tags: python, python3, anaconda, anaconda3

Anaconda Navigator を起動時にロード中のマークが表示されるのみで起動しません。

エラーコードとしては、以下のような状況です。

```
Tried to load advertisement data from https://www.anaconda.com/api/navigator. URL is not reachable
```

上記のアドレスにアクセスしたところ、404エラーが表示されます。

再インストールなどは試したのですが上手くいっておりません。

**実行環境:**

- Anaconda3
- Windows10

解決方法をご教示いただけると嬉しいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 後半が微妙に違いますが類似？/マルチポスト？ [Anaconda Navigatorを再インストールしても、起動ができない](https://teratail.com/questions/309319)

Comment: ちなみに`Anaconda Prompt`の方は起動出来るのでしょうか？ そちらが起動出来るのなら、既に実行済みかもしれませんが、そこで`conda update conda`と`conda update --all`を実行してみてはどうでしょう？ 起動出来ないなら、その状況も追記すると何かの足しになるかもしれません。

Comment: 私の環境からだと表示されている URL `https://www.anaconda.com/api/navigator` にアクセスできました。質問者さんの環境ではプロキシーや特殊なアンチウイルスソフトなどお使いではありませんでしょうか？

Comment: 例えば会社からアクセスしているとすると、`https://www.anaconda.com/api/navigator`で取得した中身の`redirect_url`や`image_url`で示す先が「寄付」を促すページなので、会社のゲートウェイ/プロキシの設定としてブロック対象になっているのかもしれませんね。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
https://www.anaconda.com/api/navigator.
にアクセスすると、
Oops this page is missing!
と表記されたページが出ます。

会社で使用しているパソコンのことなので、プロキシ周りが絡んでいるかもしれません。